# Changing the SQL generated by DBT

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, dbt, scd

Looking for some guidance, pointers about building SCD2 dimension using DBT's snapshot.

Few specific things that I am looking at

How to change the generated SQL so that dbt_valid_from, dbt_valid_to columns are named start_date, end_date (I can build a view on top of the base table but would prefer learning modifying the column names). I presume DBT's macros can be overridden but not sure which one and how to do it.

Use date other than system date to be used for these columns (e.g. a parameter that will be passed in)

Introduce additional columns in snapshot table e.g. current_indicator (boolean flag) set to Y for the latest record

Answer (score 1):

You *could* create your own version of the snapshot macro, which is kind of like a materialization. The source for the postgres macro (which is used by Redshift) can be found [here](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/blob/main/plugins/postgres/dbt/include/postgres/macros/materializations/snapshot_merge.sql). If you create a macro in your own project with the same name (`postgres__snapshot_merge_sql`), dbt will use your macro instead of the global one.

But that's probably not a great idea. Instead, I would recommend:

1. Using the built-in snapshot
2. In the snapshot, compute any additional columns you need for your logic
3. Build a model that references the snapshot (this could be materialized as a view, as you mention, or anything else), and tweak the column names and values in that model